# Django Custom user model creation NOT NULL constraint failed error

Tags: django, django-models

Im creating a custom user model with AbstractUser on django and i get that error when i create new user. Im using shell for create user: `CustomUser.objects.create(email="testmaiil2323@gmail.com", name="test name aasxs", business_name="asdkasdk sl", password="testpass234")`

Im succefull created superuser with command createsuperuser, but when i make a new users django tells me: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: apirest_customuser.business_id

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        if not extra_fields.get('business_name'):
            raise ValueError(_('The Business name must be set'))
        if not extra_fields.get('name'):
            raise ValueError(_('The Name must be set'))
        if not password:
            raise ValueError(_('The Passowrd must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        business = Business.objects.create(name=extra_fields.get('business_name'))
        profile = Profile.objects.create(name=extra_fields.get('name'))
        user = self.model(email=email, business=business, profile=profile, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    business = models.OneToOneField(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['business_name', 'name']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

i expected to create user with new profile and business

Answer (score 0):

Use `create_user` instead of `create`.

`create` method does not know about your logic of getting `business` from `business_name`. (And the same for the other fields.)